# How to pan on google maps?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, intel-xdk

I'm working on simple App which provide for our clients our branches location, I use now a snapshot of the map, but I want to show the location on real map (Pan) not just an image.

I use Intel XDK platform (HTML/Javascribt)

This is the code I use:

```js
function onError(error) {
    alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
          'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}

        
        var output = document.getElementById("mapp");
        function success(position) {
    var latitude  = position.coords.latitude;
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

    output.innerHTML = '<p>Latitude is ' + latitude + '° <br>Longitude is ' + longitude + '°</p>';

    var img = new Image();
    img.src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" + latitude + "," + longitude + "&zoom=13&size=400x400&sensor=false";

    output.appendChild(img);
  };
  
        
        output.innerHTML = "<p>Locating…</p>";
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, onError);
```

Comment: You're using the [Static Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/), which simply provides you with a PNG image.  If you want to be able to pan the map, you need to either use [Google Maps Javascript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/) or [Google Maps Embed API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, just by changing success function to:

```
var latitude  = position.coords.latitude;
var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

var bangalore = { lat: 12.97, lng: 77.59 };
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapp'), {
zoom: 14,
center: bangalore
});
```

var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: bangalore,
    map: map,
    });